# Space Invaders Syntax error on last line of code and random letter on python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

beginner here, I was trying to create a space invaders program in Python 3.7, but when I try to run this script in the terminal, it gives me this error:

```
border_pen.hideturtle()
         ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Full script:

```
import turtle
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")

delay = input("Press enter to finish.")

border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pensize(3)
border_pen.pendown()
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()
```

Comment: Any chance you have non-printable characters in your code? Did you copy-paste any of it from the web?

Comment: It does not give an error when I run just the program is crashing

Comment: If you're entering your code in the REPL, which is probably what you mean by 'terminal', you need to enter an empty line at the end of each indented block before continuing with a non-indented line. This would have been clearer for us if you had included in your question the real, complete error message, which, for me, starts with `File "<stdin>", line 4`. Always include your complete error traceback in your future questions! For your question: don't try to run long scripts in the REPL, it's not really convenient for that. Or remember to include an empty line at the end of indented blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code locally and it gives none syntax error. But there is an issue in your code. If you are willing to see the white borders you should place the `input()` the end because when it is in the middle it stays there till enter is pressed and not read the rest of the code and when entered just run the rest but you are not able to see any white borders because it is too fast.

```
import turtle
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")

delay = input("Delay") # this one is for delay

border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pensize(3)
border_pen.pendown()
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()
input('Press enter to exit') # for exiting
```

Take a look at [image: this] I screened from my local machine.